# Cannot capture output of java -version using os.popen

Tags: java, python, printing, version, popen

Here is my code

```
    f = os.popen("java -version")
    for i in f.readlines():
        print "result, ", i,
```

Basically I want the output of java -version to be stored in f.  What happens is, after the first line of the script executes, the java -version information is printed out, but not stored in f, hence the third line of code is not executed at all.  This code works for other commands such as "ls -la", but not for java -version.  Any ideas as to why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: output of java -version goes to stderr

Answer (score 1):

try something like:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
stdout,stderr= Popen(['java','-version'], shell=False, stderr=PIPE).communicate()
print(stderr)
```

**output:**

```
b'java version "1.6.0_20"\nOpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.9.13) (6b20-1.9.13-0ubuntu1~10.10.1)\nOpenJDK Client VM (build 19.0-b09, mixed mode, sharing)\n'
```

Comment: @user1410747 my mistake it should be `stderr=PIPE`, now it'll work.

Answer (score 1):

Since `java -version` goes to stderr, not to stdin, you have to redirect it:

```
f = os.popen("java -version 2>&1")
for i in f.readlines():
    print "result, ", i,
```

better yet, use the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) module, which is designed to make this kind of things easier:

```
print subprocess.check_output("java -version", stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
```